# My Files are not Copying or Moving - Why?

Tags: powershell

My code is not copying the files in the folder to my backup location or moving the files to the destination folders...  Please Help!!

Set the source, backup and destination folder paths

```
$sourcePath1 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Documents"
$sourcePath2 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Haas-NC"
$sourcePath3 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Mounting"
$sourcePath4 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Orders"
$backupPath1 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Documents\Backup"
$backupPath2 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Haas-NC\Backup"
$backupPath3 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Mounting\Backup"
$backupPath4 = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Orders\Backup"
$destPath1 = "T:\public\640TXPLAQUES\Documents"
$destPath2 = "T:\public\640TXPLAQUES\Haas-NC"
$destPath3 = "T:\public\640TXPLAQUES\Mounting"
$destPath4 = "T:\public\640TXPLAQUES\Orders"
```

Get a list of files in the source folder paths

```
$files1 = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath1
$files2 = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath2
$files3 = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath3
$files4 = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath4
```

Copy the files from the source folders to the backup folders, replacing any existing files with the same name

```
foreach ($file in $files1) {
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $backupPath1 -Force
}
foreach ($file in $files2) {
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $backupPath2 -Force
}
foreach ($file in $files3) {
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $backupPath3 -Force
}
foreach ($file in $files4) {
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $backupPath4 -Force
}
```

Move the files from the source folders to the destination folders, replacing any existing files with the same name

```
foreach ($file in $files1) {
    Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $destPath1 -Force
}
foreach ($file in $files2) {
    Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $destPath2 -Force
}
foreach ($file in $files3) {
    Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $destPath3 -Force
}
foreach ($file in $files4) {
    Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $destPath4 -Force
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try with one specific file, on the command line—without any loops or `Get-ChildItem` or whatever. Does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks very overcomplicated, this should just work:

```
# Define a List
$folderSets = @(
  # With HashTables that store related paths as properties
  @{
    Source = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Documents"
    Destination = "T:\public\640TXPLAQUES\Documents"
    Backup = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Documents\Backup"
  }
  @{
    Source = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Haas-NC"
    Destination = "T:\public\640TXPLAQUES\Haas-NC"
    Backup = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Haas-NC\Backup"  
  }
  @{
    Source = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Mounting"
    Destination = "T:\public\640TXPLAQUES\Mounting"
    Backup = "Z:\Texas_Transfer\Mounting\Backup"  
  }
  # Etc.
)

# Loop through the list and copy/move all files
foreach ($folderSet in $folderSets) {
  Copy-Item -Path "$($folderSet.Source)\*" -Destination $folderSet.Backup -Force
  Move-Item -Path "$($folderSet.Source)\*" -Destination $folderSet.Destination -Force
}
```

Note that the directories to copy/move to need to exist, else you need to create them in the script with `New-Item`

And of course you were missing `-Path` argument in most of your commands, which is something you should include for readability.

If the structure is always similar like that, you could simplify it even further by just having the list of sources and building the paths based on them.

Answer (score 1):

#### My code is not copying the files to my backup location or moving the files to the destination folders

> `-path string`
>
> The path(s) to the items. Wildcards are permitted.
>
> Use a dot (.) to specify the current location. **The default is the current directory**.
>
> Use the wildcard (*) to specify all items in the current location.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

`copy-item` and `move-item` both have to have `-path` as the first argument if the file is not in the current directory.

See [Copy-Item - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/copy-item.html) and [Move-Item - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/move-item.html)

Comment: Specifying `-path` is optional. It’s always the first argument, whether named or not. Everything else would be very surprising, after all. Indeed, you can even leave out `-destination`.